# How to start contributing?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , I am interested to work with ROS as a part of OPW internship for this winter . Can somebody please help me as to how I should start working or if there is any person whom I can contact for further information .

Thanks ,

Regards,
Myra

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192883/how-to-start-contributing-?/) by [Myra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20223/myra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone interested in participating in the GNOME Outreach Program for
Women (OPW) on an OSRF project (ROS, Gazebo, etc), please contact
opw at osrfoundation.org and we will give further instruction.

More information on OPW in general can be found at: http://gnome.org/opw/

OSRF has a page on our wiki with information about projects and application criteria:
http://wiki.osrfoundation.org/opw14 Also feel free to suggest a project of your own.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1